# $\frac{1}{2} x^tQx+c^t+ \gamma$ is convex iff $Q$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^tQx+c^tx+ \gamma$$ for symmetric $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Show that $f$ is convex iff $Q$ is positive semidefinite.

We know that a function $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $X$ iff for all $x,y \in X$ hold:

$$f(x) - f(y) \ge \nabla f(y)^t (x-y)$$

I tried to use this theorem and  thus calculated that $\nabla f(x) = x^tQ+c^t$. Using the above theorem this and the definition of $f$ this yields (after some elementary algebra):

$$\frac{1}{2} x^tQx \ge \frac{1}{2} y^tQy + y^tQ(x-y).$$

I do not know how to proceed from here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: I believe you forgot an $x$ in the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong.

Consider the case $Q=0$, $c=0$.
Then $f$ is convex, but $Q$ not positive definite.

**edit**:
For positive semidefinite $Q$, the statement should be true.

As a hint: the final inequality that you got is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^tQ(x-y) \ge 0.$$
Then it remain to use the definition of positive semidefiniteness for $Q$
and you obtain both directions.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been semidefinite.

Comment: I edited to give you a hint for the semidefinite case.

Comment: Side note: the result can also be proven by computing the Hessian.